# Unable to display Upvote/Downvote count in Rail app views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-votable

I'm currently using the 'acts_as_votable' Ruby gem to give the Upvote/Downvote function to comments in a basic rails app. In the comments_controller.rb the functions look like this:

```
    def upvote
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
      @comment.upvote_by current_user
      redirect_to comments_path
    end

    def downvote
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
      @comment.downvote_by current_user
      redirect_to comment_path
    end
```

and in the roputes.rb:

```
  resources :comments do
    member do
     put "like", to: "comments#upvote"
     put "dislike", to: "comments#downvote"
    end
  end
```

and the loop in the views looks like this:

```
 <div class="box">
 <% @comment.each do |w| %>
    <tr>        
      <td><b><%= w.title %></b></td><br>
      <td><%= w.location %></td><br>
      <td><%= w.body %></td><br> 
      <%= link_to "upvote", like_comment_path(w), method: :put %>
      <%= @comment.upvote_by.size %>
      <%= link_to "downvote", dislike_comment_path(w), method: :put %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

There are no problems with this, except for with this line of code:

```
<%= @comment.upvote_by.size %>
```

which is returning the following error:

```
undefined method `upvote_by' for #
<Comment::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007faa8dbf0560>
```

I'm not sure why the method is undefined as I assume this is either a method that is built in to the gem, or a ruby method. I also don't know if this is an error message that is thrown up for some other reason, but I'm not sure what this could be. I've tried to use 'upvote_from' instead but this didn't work. If I remove the line then the app runs fine.

I can't work out what else could be causing this, so I would really appreciate some help here, thanks.

Comment: why are you calling `@comment.each` ? Where did  you get the view example from ? What are you trying to show exactly ?

Comment: This is in the comments/index which is why I'm using the loop. I'm just trying to she number of votes per comment at the moment.

Comment: Then I think it should be `@comments` instead of `@comment`. And  did you try to call `upvote_by` on `w` directly ?

Comment: Do you mean like this:  <%= @comment.votes_for.size(w) %>? I tried this but the results were the same

Comment: Sorry I meant `w.votes_for.size`

Comment: Yes! That totally worked - thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside an index, I would recommand to use `@comments` instead of `@comment`, I would also rename `w` for `comment` so that it's more clear it's a comment.

```
<div class="box">
 <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    <tr>        
      <td><b><%= comment.title %></b></td><br>
      <td><%= comment.location %></td><br>
      <td><%= comment.body %></td><br> 
      <%= link_to "upvote", like_comment_path(comment), method: :put %>
      <%= comment.upvote_by.size %>
      <%= link_to "downvote", dislike_comment_path(comment), method: :put %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately none of those 'tally them up' methods work in the same place, so I guess it's not that. All of the methods are still showing as undefined, and that's got me really confused.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to run the migrations :

```
rails generate acts_as_votable:migration
rake db:migrate
```

Add this in your comment model ( comment.rb )

```
acts_as_votable
```

More details in the [doc](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable)

> Database Migrations
>
> Acts As Votable uses a votes table to store all voting information. To
>   generate and run the migration just use.
>
> rails generate acts_as_votable:migration rake db:migrate
>
> You will get a performance increase by adding in cached columns to
>   your model's tables. You will have to do this manually through your
>   own migrations. See the caching section of this document for more
>   information.
>
> Usage Votable Models
>
> class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
>      acts_as_votable
>
> end